# Undefined Reference to weak functions (Static Library + GCC)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, static, linker

**Hello everybody.
First, I would like to introduce my problem to you all!**

I am using Atollic TrueStudio to develop an Embedded System. In this system, I have a driver layer (built as a static library. This library contains basically the STM32 HAL, and this library contains A LOT of weak functions).
These library is being compiled with ARM GCC and works great. I can link it in other projects and it does work as it should.

**The second part is the problem, because I want to implement Unit Testing in the project!**

For this, I have created another configuration for the same Driver Layer static library (the one with STM32 HAL code), but this time I'm compiling it with MinGW.
The compilation works, but when I Try to link this library into another project (an executable project). The Linker returns "undefined reference to ..." (Image below).

PS: The problem is with the Linker, since the project finds where the weak function is declared. It can not find where it's defined though!

**Edit**

**This is the main code**

```
#include <MbedOS/platform/mbed_error.h>

int main(void)
{
   error("Stream obj failure, errno=%d\r\n",

   return 0;
}
```

**This is where the function is defined (inside the static library) mbed_error.c**

```
#include <MbedOS/platform/mbed_error.h>

static uint8_t error_in_progress = 0;

WEAK void error(const char* format,
                ...)
{

   // Prevent recursion if error is called again
   if (error_in_progress)
   {
      return;
   }

   error_in_progress = 1;

   #ifndef NDEBUG
      va_list arg;
      va_start(arg,
               format);
      mbed_error_vfprintf(format,
                          arg);
      va_end(arg);
   #endif

   exit(1);
}
```

**This is mbed_error.h file**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
void error(const char* format,
           ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

**And this is the result from the console**

```
13:45:44 **** Build of configuration Debug for project testeLINKER ****
make all 
gcc -o "testeLINKER.elf"  ./src/main.o   -lSTM32F7_Driver_Layer -L"E:\TrueStudio_Projects\STM32F7_Driver_Layer\Projeto\TrueStudio\UnitTestLibrary"
./src/main.o: In function `main':
E:\TrueStudio_Projects\testeLINKER\Debug/../src/main.c:33: undefined reference to `error'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testeLINKER.elf] Error 1

13:45:44 Build Finished (took 460ms)
```

**Edit 2 
 The nm output for the static library follows (just one of the files with a weak function)**

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.0\PCTools\bin>nm E:\TrueStudio_Projects\STM32F7_Driver_Layer\Projeto\TrueStudio\UnitTestLibrary\Source\MbedOS\platform\mbed_error.o
00000000 b .bss
00000000 d .data
00000000 N .debug_abbrev
00000000 N .debug_aranges
00000000 N .debug_info
00000000 N .debug_line
00000000 r .eh_frame
00000000 r .rdata$zzz
00000000 t .text
00000000 T .weak._error.
         w _error
00000000 b _error_in_progress
         U _exit
         U _mbed_error_vfprintf
```

Comment: Sure, if it'd be better (: Im gonna edit the topic

Comment: It's not just better, it becomes acceptable by that. A collection of problems and solutions doesn't work if any part depends on some volatile external resource.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It'll be a lot easier for us to figure out your problem if you include your code as text in the body of your question. Just paste it in, select it, and then click the `{ }` button to format it as code.

Comment: Now it should be better! If you could please take a look (:

Comment: I am going to edit again the post to add the nm map (:

Comment: You don't show the #include lines, so as to see if the declaration of "error" is on scope. You don't show if the directories to search in are properly given to the linker.

Comment: I've edited the post again with the #include preprocessor.

But The problem is within the Linker if I'm not wrong, because the compilation works fine

Comment: If `mbed_error.c` is compiled as a library, the add this library (an `.a` file) to the gcc command. If it's just an `.o` file, then give this file to gcc command.

Comment: I'm doing this, gcc -o "testeLINKER.elf"  ./src/main.o    -static -L"E:\TrueStudio_Projects\STM32F7_Driver_Layer\Projeto\TrueStudio\UnitTestLibrary" "E:\TrueStudio_Projects\STM32F7_Driver_Layer\Projeto\TrueStudio\UnitTestLibrary\libSTM32F7_Driver_Layer.a"..

But the problems is still happening

Comment: @Ripi2, I just added here one file, but the library consists in more than 200 files (more or less)

Comment: `.a` files are added like `-lmyLib.a` after the files that need them. `.o` files (already compiled, but not linked) are added like `-o myOfile.o` Review your `.a` adding.

Comment: But I am doing exaclty the same thing for the ARM configuration and it is working. It is only not working for the MinGW config!

Furthermore, the Atollic TrueStudio IDE configs for me the MakeFile

Answer (score 1):

For everyone that may have the same doubt as I had. Here's the answer.

The problem is that PE32 file format does not support weak linkage.